# Magento filter Collection by Date attribute value

Tags: magento-1.9, magento-1.8, php-7

I would like to know. How can i filter collection by attributes specially When Catalog Input Type for Store Owner is DATE.

Each product will have a future date when there stock will be set as out of stock no matter what is stock qty. And i want to pragmatically set this by filter product based on that future date if future date match with any product that product will set as out of stock. I just dont know how can filter product based on a future date where i can check if its match with that date or not. I hope you understand.

Answer (score 1):

**In Your Collection You Can Apply Date Filter Using Start to End Date :-**

```
$fromDate = date('Y-m-d H:i:s', strtotime('-1 hour')); //Start Date
$toDate = date('Y-m-d H:i:s', strtotime(now()));       // End Date
$collection->addFieldToFilter('your_attribute', array(
    'from' => $fromDate,
    'to' => $toDate,
    'date' => true,
    ));
```

Comment: I am not trying to filter from created date. I am trying to filter by a attribute which type is date.

Comment: yes you will replace created_at to your attribute

Comment: Aha thats right but this is what i want to achieve. The date attribute will have future date and i want to filter collection whatever match with future date.

Comment: please explain clearly you hve 1 attribute "future_date"

Comment: you can filter using "future_date" attribute ???